# Service is getting restart when app is killed

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play a music in service. Problem is when I am killing the app my music stops and starts itself from beginning. How can I Keep my music running smoothly. Here is my code:

```
public class EngineBackground extends Service {

    static MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if(player == null){
            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.aajraate);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add action in onStartCommand and put action based conditions

Comment: Try playing `MediaPlayer` in `foreground` with a attached notification to it will keep service alive while its killed.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior.

Do not kill applications.

If your users do so, including by swiping out of recents, they will have to accept the momentary interruption of playback which results until Android re-creates your service and it resumes playing.

You may be able to get slightly better results by running your background service in its own process using manifest attributes, but you still cannot consider any of your code immune from being killed - for example, it may still happen if something in the foreground needs more resources.

Comment: but my phone's default music player keeps playing music without any interruption. How to do it?